# Extract a month from a date

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I'm trying to build a query with propel Criteria to get all Foo's in a given month.

For example I want all Foo's in March. In regular SQL I would build a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FooPeer WHERE MONTH(startDate) = 3
```

Any Idea how I can implement the "MySQL Month-function within a Criteria Object" ?

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c -> add(FooEvent::START_DATE, 3, Criteria::EQUAL); //where do I have to put the Month function ?
return self::doSelect($c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, a Custom Criteria did the job!

```
$month = 3; //march
$criteria->add(FooPeer::START_DATE, 'MONTH('.FooPeer::START_DATE.')='. $month, Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was partly answered there: [How to use MySQL functions in Propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260229/how-to-use-mysql-functions-in-propel)

Using Criteria::CUSTOM or writing custom SQL seem to be the only solutions.